# Elasticsearch terms query is very slow?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-6.8

Elasticsearch cluster

```
Master node : 1 (16cpus, 128GB RAM) - 32GB is allocated for HEAP
Data nodes  : 6 (each node 16cpus, 128GB RAM) - 32GB is allocated for 
HEAP for all nodes

Indices : 9 
Total documents : 48,826,456
Stored size : 2TB
```

This [query](https://pastebin.pl/view/e2334807) is very slow. Takes around `4seconds`

I have profiled it and found terms **profile_id** in the filter is slow, Since terms array contains around 20k ids. `Without terms` it takes around `700ms`

Any suggestion to improve the performance will be grateful.

Comment: didn't you ask the similar question few days back?

Comment: wow. what a huge query. I think 4s is very good response.

Comment: Did you check the explain: true result? Could you provide it to check the query?

Comment: And also, the title is wrong. there are also range filter on your query :)

Comment: if you have static queries like this, I suggest  to update by query your data and add two field. add a field for "OR part" and add field for 'term part". something like building category.